# structure question

Tags: sql, database-design

I Have a realtional db i am putting together, with the help of members here i have most of it done.. thank you everyone.  however i am stuck on how to do one last part.

its for tracking cell phone line sales inhouse.

so each customer can have multiple orders
each order can have multiple lines
each line has one plan attached to it
each line can have multiple addons (hotspot service, insurnace etc)

i have everything done except i am having issues with teh multiple addon services.

I have a TBL Lines with the following structure

```
ID_Key
Phone-Num
Customer_FK (Foreign Key to customer table)
Plan_FK (Foreign key to Plan Type Table)
Serial_Number
Order_FK (Foreign Key to Order_Details Table)
```

I was then thinking of adding in another field called

```
Service_FK (Foreign Key to a table that is made up of the following)
```

TblServiceOrder

```
SeriviceID (References TblServiceType)
LineID (references ID_KEY from TBl Lines)
```

The Tbl Service Type is a table with just

```
ID (Primary Key)
Description
```

Eg. --> 
ID 132 -->Insurance
ID 133 --> Hotspot

Am I heading down the right path ?

I will want to be able to pull a report on the details of each order . e.g.

Customer: 1234  Orders 2 Lines, Line 1 has plan 103, Line 2 has plan 104.  Line 1 also has Insruance and has a hotspot added, Line 2 just has insurance.

thanks for all your help

Pat

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to add a `Service_FK` field to the `Lines` table. The relationship is already expressed by the new table having the `LineID` in it.

Comment: thanks Dan, Sorry I had that taken out but forgot to update the post.. but do you think i am on the right path ?